# how to delete a particular file from the files list?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My Objective is to delete a particular file from the file list but when I want to delete the last file is being deleted instead of the required file.

Here is the code:

```
 {this.state.myFiles.map(file => (
        <p key={file.name}>
          {file.name} ({file.size} bytes)
          <button
            className={"material-icons delete"}
            onClick={() => this.handleRemoveFile(file.name)}
          >
            Remove file
          </button>
        </p>))}
```

Removing particular file from the files list:

```
handleRemoveFile = (fileName) => {
const myFiles = [...this.state.myFiles];
 myFiles.splice(myFiles.indexOf(fileName), 1)
        this.setState({ myFiles })
}
```

I couldn't able to delete a particular file, it is deleting the last one from the file list, can anyone help me in removing the particular file from the file list?

Thanks! in advance.

Comment: `myFiles.indexOf(fileName)` does not work, as fileName is a string and myFiles is an array of objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map` gives you a second argument which is the index of the array.

```
 {this.state.myFiles.map((file,index) => (
        <p key={file.name}>
          {file.name} ({file.size} bytes)
          <button
            className={"material-icons delete"}
            onClick={() => this.handleRemoveFile(index)}
          >
            Remove file
          </button>
        </p>))}
```

Now you can use this index to filter the file

```
handleRemoveFile = (fileIndexToRemove) => {
   const updatedFiles = this.state.myFiles.filter((file, index) => index !== fileIndexToRemove)
   this.setState({ myFiles: updatedFiles  })
}
```

Comment: it is showing error as undefined

Comment: I think we wont get id for the respective file

Comment: no need to use the id , just use the array index . the filter condition has to be index !== fileIndexToRemove

Comment: Still i'm getting error

Comment: what is the error ? . Add the complete error message or attach a screenshot .

Comment: Sorry thats my bad, i made a small mistake. You're right